# Is there any command in Code-based EF migration to re-create the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I am using ASP.NET MVC4. I am switching to a test-database which already exists. **Is there any code-based migration command to drop and re-create the database, say for example Update-Database-DropCreate**.

I don't want to use any database-initializer such as `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` because when I switch back to the live database I will have to manually remove the initializer code. Is there any other way to accomplish this so that I don't have to make any changes when I use the live database later.

I tried `Update-Database -force` but it does not re-create the database.

Comment: As far as I understand you would like to apply migrations on existing database? You could achive that with context.Database.MigrateAsync() or simply by adding config section in appsettings.json to indicate if you are using development env. and trigger method on dev only and change that setting on rest of env.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you r using dependency injection and injecting your context class using a container you can create different context for test db with initialization strategy and leave the original one as it is  all u have to do is change the injected context or even add a context factory to create specific context depending on environment

if this is to complex then another way would be add the initialization strategy to your context and add a condition to check if this is the test or production server (you can know that from the connection string which u can get from the context)

Comment: thank you; it would also be very helpful if you can paste some code snippets for the two mentioned approaches.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this via migration commands you can simply run the command with -TargetMigration 0 and then do an Update-Database again.

Comment: Take a backup, just in case :)

Comment: Also, any reason, just right-click Delete on DB in SSMS with drop existing connections wouldn't just work? Meaning do you need a command to do this? Just running Update-Database should get you back then as well.

Comment: I have multiple migrations (created with live database). What is the point of running all the -TargetMigrations one by one, just to re-create the test-database?

Comment: No, not one by one. You run two commands: 1) "Update-Database -TargetMigration 0" and 2) "Update-Database". The first one will roll them all back (this is me assuming you want to clear out the data and the second will create schema (and lookup data if in migrations)

Comment: I made few edits to your answer. Kindly check and confirm; edit further if you feel.